# How to add the 'markersize' argument to a DataFrame plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a DataFrame and I want to modify the markersize, but it seems like I cannot do it in the same plot() call.

```
ax0 = df_can_t.plot(kind='scatter', x='Year', y='China', \
figsize=(30,10), color = 'red', marker= '+', markersize = 14.0)
```

I am getting the error: AttributeError: Unknown property markersize.

However, it seems like 'markersize' is allowed (https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: You are using `scatter`, not `plot`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [scatter plot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), you the size parameter is just `s`, try:

```
ax0 = df_can_t.plot(kind='scatter', x='Year', y='China', \
figsize=(30,10), color = 'red', marker= '+', s = 14.0)
```

Here is a MVCE:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

ax = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='petal_width', y='sepal_width', s=10.0)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks. I suppose https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html says: "New in version 0.17.0: Each plot kind has a corresponding method on the DataFrame.plot accessor: df.plot(kind='line') is equivalent to df.plot.line()."